# How to refresh a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeter in page. I set datasource for it in page load.

```
 LikeRepeater.DataSource = clsForumQuestionLikeViewFactory.GetAllByFieldDT(clsForumQuestionLikeView.clsForumQuestionLikeViewFields.QuestionID, id);
 LikeRepeater.DataBind();
```

I have a linkbutton. when click it, I add a record to database and set datatsource for repeater.

```
protected void ParentLikeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LikeRepeater.DataSource = clsForumQuestionLikeViewFactory.GetAllByFieldDT(clsForumQuestionLikeView.clsForumQuestionLikeViewFields.QuestionID, IDLabel.Value);
 LikeRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

It have two item but show one, Repeater don't refresh.

How to refresh it?

Comment: which version of .net are you using? have you tried searching the documentation for something like : `LikeRepeater.refresh()` ? is the LikeRepeater a class? because it gets highlighted as class here. i guess its an object though ...

Comment: also this is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463317/how-to-dynamically-refresh-a-net-databound-repeater-control

Comment: are you adding to the database first and then fetching?

Comment: @Vogel612 :Thanks , I use .net 4.5... i use `databind()` but don't refresh.

Comment: @krshekhar: Yes, when i use pointer, repeater have two item but show one, don't refresh :(

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: @krshekhar : yes i use :(

Comment: Then it looks like it is an update panel issue, not a repeater issue. try putting a breakpoint on the `LikeRepeater.DataSource = ` in the click event. Check how many items are returned. I'll venture a guess that it is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

your datasource is updated ParentLikeButton_Click event but on page load event you set old datasource. so every time you add data might be updated but from page load it takes old data so you need to bind data in  if(!isPostback) condition 
    like this
    in page load event check condition
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {bind data here for first time}

Comment: I set datasource in  `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: and i think your method clsForumQuestionLikeViewFactory.GetAllByFieldDT returns only single value is it so?? check it out.. :)

Answer (score -2):

1. add "LikeRepeater.DataSource = null" before Setting its

Comment: strange answer. Why to put it `null` in data source if he is providing a new `data source` to the `LikeRepeater`

Comment: Thanks. I set null, but don't refresh.